# How do I find the time the user changed their password using the Google APIs?

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-api-python-client, google-admin-sdk, google-apps-for-education

This is for users in Google Apps for Business or Education.

Using the Reports API in the Admin SDK I can see when the admin changed another user's password, but I cannot find an API that will tell me when a user has changed their password.  I have changed mine twice in the past couple days and it does not come up in Reports API any where.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, that's the answer.